# Kali install freezes trying to find network drivers

Tags: boot, operating-systems, kali-linux

Kali install freezes trying to find network drivers, so I can't install the OS in any way. I've already tried booting from DVD and USB, with two different versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some bugs during Kali's installation, this is one of them. All I had to to is to restart the computer, open up the BIOS and disable network drivers for the time of installation, then press escape when "detecting network drivers" showed up. (if you're facing the same issue, don't forget to re-enable wireless drivers on the next boot, so you can start using internet on your new operating system).